# What are the possible user.agent values in gwt.xml?

Tags: xml, gwt, properties

I was wondering what are the possible user.agent values in gwt.xml. I found some of them but unfortunately not the complete list.

- Chrome - safari
- Firefox - gecko1_8
- Internet Explorer 6 - ie6

What are the others?? Opera, ie7, ie8, ... etc.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Depends on the version of GWT, but here's the [latest definition.](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/main/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml) (Recently all IE9 / IE10 has been removed)

**UPDATE**: the module has moved from `com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent` to `com.google.gwt.useragent.UserAgent`, link above updated.

**UPDATE 2**: GWT sources have moved to gwt.googlesource.com

**Update 3**: GWT sources have moved to github.com, link updated.

Comment: The list of supported `user.agent` property values was removed from [the latest version of UserAgent.gwt.xml](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwt.xml), that is opened with your link. Now it can be found in [the r9835 version of that file](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwt.xml?r=9835).

Comment: It has actually been moved to [`com.google.gwt.useragent.UserAgent`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml) (and the `com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent` module is only kept for backwards compatibility)

Comment: And the correspondence between `user.agent` codes and browsers? How can I know which one corresponds to, for example, Google Chrome.

Comment: Found it, here are the "user.agent" codes and the JS used to identify which one will be used for a given browser.

Comment: [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml)