# What is my user.agent version?

Tags: gwt

I want to speed up my compilation with GWT. I'd like to know my gecko verion to use : `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko..."/>`

When I look at Firefox informations, I have : *Agent utilisateur Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0*

So what value am I suppose to put ? Where could I find this information for next versions ?
Same question for Chrome wich only gives me *Version 29.0.1547.66 m*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the possible user.agent values in gwt.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992678/what-are-the-possible-user-agent-values-in-gwt-xml)

Comment: I confirm it's a duplicate. The question did not appear in the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gecko` refers to very old versions of Mozilla, while `gecko1_8` refers to all modern versions, including all versions of Firefox 2.0 and later. `gecko` permutation was removed some time ago.

So for FF just set `gecko1_8`

Comment: gecko has already been removed from GWT. Only gecko1_8 can be used, as far as Firefox is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox (Gecko) use

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />
```

But it depends of the GWT version. Other possible values are ie6, ie8, gecko1_8, safari, opera, ie9.